# How can I stop Solve returning the value of a root encapsulated in a list?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a `Solve` similar to the following:

```
Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15, {e, c}, Integers]
(* {{e -> -7, c -> -8}, {e -> -7, c -> 8}, {e -> -1, c -> -4}, 
    {e -> -1, c -> 4}, {e -> 1, c -> -4}, {e -> 1, c -> 4}, 
    {e -> 7, c -> -8}, {e -> 7, c -> 8}} *)
```

I need to add a region constraint to get the solution I want from the unconstrained list of solutions. I tried the following:

```
Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 ∧ {e, c} ∈ Interval[{0, 4}], {e, c}, Integers]
(* {{e -> {1}, c -> {4}}} *)
```

However, when I do this it wraps the variable's solutions in `List`.  Is there a way to turn this off so I just get `{{e -> 1, c -> 4}}` or `{e -> 1, c -> 4}` as the result? The current result is a pain as I have to massage it for use with `Replace`. Also, can any explain why it is doing this when I constrain the variables?

Comment: Whether constrained or not, `Solve` returns a list of solutions (and this is quite clear from the refguide page). To do otherwise would be a huge incompatibility in form of result. Extracting the first solution, say, is readily done with `First` or `Part`. Again, all well documented.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You've obviously not read the question.

Comment: Actually I read it twice. But it did not improve with the second go round.

Comment: e.g. the constrained one gives `e -> {1}` instead of `e -> 1` as the unconstrained one gives.

Comment: Ah. I should have read it a third time. Not sure what is going on here, it might be a bug.

Comment: Not a solution, just a workaround `Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 && And @@ Thread[0 <= {e, c} <= 4], {e,  c}, Integers]`

Comment: This seemingly weird result is actually documented behavior. See the refguide page for `Solve`, under `Scope > Geometric Regions`, in particular the last example. The gist is that if `x` is an element of a region-type thing (which `Interval[...]` is) then it is a vector. Several examples are of the form `Element[{x,y}, twoDimRegion]` and in that specification `{x, y}` is the vector but `x' and `y` are each scalars. For your example, an analog would be `Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 ∧ {{e}, {c}} ∈ Interval[{0, 4}], {e, c}, Integers]`.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Yes, I see. I've obviously not read all of the documentation. :-P  I might have made the link that it was doing the 1D region thing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interval is a 1D region, so `Element[e, Interval[...]]` makes e a 1D vector
not a scalar. If you want `e` to be a scalar use `Element[{e}, Interval[...]]`.

```
In[1]:= Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 && Element[{e}|{c}, Interval[{0, 4}]], {e, c}, Integers]

Out[1]= {{e -> 1, c -> 4}}
```

Compare to:

```
In[2]:= Solve[Element[e, Disk[]], e, Integers]

Out[2]= {{e -> {-1, 0}}, {e -> {0, -1}}, {e -> {0, 0}}, {e -> {0, 1}},
>    {e -> {1, 0}}}

In[3]:= Solve[Element[{x, y}, Disk[]], {x, y}, Integers]

Out[3]= {{x -> -1, y -> 0}, {x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 0, y -> 0},
>    {x -> 0, y -> 1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}
```

Comment: This was my first thought.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 2):

The `Interval` seems to be the problem, it returns an "Interval Object" and, rather than figure out what that is, just use the `<=` operator to state the conditions explicitly

```
Solve[
 e^2 - c^2 == -15 && 0 <= e <= 4 && 0 <= c <= 4, {e, c}, Integers]
(* {{e -> 1, c -> 4}} *)
```

or

```
Solve[{e^2 - c^2 == -15, 0 <= e <= 4, 0 <= c <= 4}, {e, 
  c}, Integers]
(* {{e -> 1, c -> 4}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The unwanted `List` also can be replaced after completing `Solve`.

```
Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 ∧ {e, c} ∈ Interval[{0, 4}], {e, c}, Integers] 
    /. Rule[z1_, {z2_}] -> Rule[z1, z2]
```

or

```
Replace[Solve[e^2 - c^2 == -15 ∧ {e, c} ∈ Interval[{0, 4}], {e, c}, Integers], 
    List[z_] -> z, -1]

(* {{e -> 1, c -> 4}} *)
```